# Ubuntu Server 13.04 on IBM x3300 M4 - boot failure

Tags: installation, boot, server, grub2

I installed Ubuntu Server 13.04 on an IBM x3300 M4 system. Everything was fine during the installation, and all the required updates were done automatically, but when the installation was completed and the system reboot was done, the system totally cannot boot up. The system keeps on rebooting and giving the following boot failure message:

```
boot failed CD/DVD Rom
boot failed HD Disk 0
```

and so on for all the devices listed.

Comment: Try this.  In the UEFI BIOS you need to add boot option "Legacy Boot" and make that your first boot device.

Answer (score 0):

I have X3300 m4 using ubuntu 12.04

when using dvd instalation i can boot via DVD and no problem with HDD. but when finish it's can't boot like it can't detect the hdd. 
i already find in google and ask the ibm, but not much help they sudgest using paid linux server like redhat and suse

So .....
i unplug the HDD from raid, i direct attach using sata cable to sata port, and install like normal. then it's finish, i can boot it. but .....
the speed of sata just SATA 2

to day, i remove DVD and change to SSD for database, still using (SATA port) and still run on sata 2, not on full speed. but it's fast enough to server mysql database.